# OpenUI5 Support for OData v4?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I was trying to use OpenUI5 with a .NET OData v4 Web API service. It looks like the client embeds the "Max OData Service Version" header with the HTTP request by default and my service doesn't like that. Additionally, documentation notes support for v2 experimental v3.

Does anyone know when support for v4 is expected?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Keep an eye on the [UI5 roadmap](https://www.sap.com/products/roadmaps.cross-topics.html) (Scroll down to "SAPUI5"). Also [this new tutorial](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bcdbde6911bd4fc68fd435cf8e306ed0) would mention what features are supported already.

Answer (score 3):

There are people working on the v4 support, but don't expect it to be available in the next few months.
Currently a new version of the v2 model is being implemented that has performance optimizations and better batch support, after that one is finished I guess the v4 support will be an important part of the agenda.

Comment: Are there any news on that? https://scn.sap.com/thread/3823437 seems to hint at v3 at least but has no clear answer... v4 was releases in march 2014. Since OData is a central part in UI5 (and the HANA-stack) I dont understand why we have to stick with the v2...

Comment: The v4 support is still WIP, you can find the code implemented as of now here: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v4

Answer (score 0):

OData V4 finaly just got released.
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel.html

But keep in mind what Jens Ittel said:

> [...] Due to its limited feature scope, we will not recommend to use
> the first of these releases of the model implementation for productive
> usage. [...]